# Preserve arbitrary order in a collection defined with JDO in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, testing, jdo, datanucleus

I am in the process of moving my code to Java7 and to the newest Datanucleus App Engine Plugin and I am stuck with the order problem.

I have an ancestor class that owns some children that need to mantain a specific order defined by the user. So that I used the @Order annotion without any @Extension.
With the previous JDO version everything worked fined and now my unit test fails because it doesn't find anymore this _INTEGER_IDX property.

I created a simple test project, following this documentation [Owned one-to-many relationship](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships) in order to start from a fresh example and still it doesn't work:
[GitHub-project](https://github.com/micheleorsi/jdo-order-test-project).

I summarize here the model:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Book {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String key = null;

    @Persistent
    private String title = null;

    @Persistent(mappedBy="book")
    @Order
    private List<Chapter> chapters = null;
```

.. and ..

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Chapter {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String key = null;

    @Persistent
    private String name = null;

    @Persistent
    private Book book = null;
```

.. and here is the Unit Test that fails:

```
@Test
public void testJdoDependingEntities() throws EntityNotFoundException {
    PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

    Book bookJdo = null;

    try {
        pm.currentTransaction().begin();

        bookJdo = new Book("myTitle");
        Chapter cpt1 = new Chapter("myname1");
        Chapter cpt2 = new Chapter("myname2");
        Chapter cpt3 = new Chapter("myname3");
        Chapter cpt4 = new Chapter("myname4");
        Chapter cpt5 = new Chapter("myname5");
        Chapter cpt6 = new Chapter("myname6");

        bookJdo.getChapters().add(cpt1);
        cpt1.setBook(bookJdo);
        bookJdo.getChapters().add(cpt2);
        cpt2.setBook(bookJdo);
        bookJdo.getChapters().add(cpt3);
        cpt3.setBook(bookJdo);
        bookJdo.getChapters().add(cpt4);
        cpt4.setBook(bookJdo);
        bookJdo.getChapters().add(cpt5);
        cpt5.setBook(bookJdo);
        bookJdo.getChapters().add(cpt6);
        cpt6.setBook(bookJdo);

        pm.makePersistent(bookJdo);

        pm.currentTransaction().commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(pm.currentTransaction().isActive()) {
            pm.currentTransaction().rollback();
        }
        pm.close();
    }

    Entity book = datastore.get(KeyFactory.stringToKey(bookJdo.getKey()));
    assertEquals("myTitle", book.getProperty("title"));

    Query query = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query(
            "Chapter",
            KeyFactory.stringToKey(bookJdo.getKey()));
    FetchOptions options = FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults();

    QueryResultList<Entity> resultEntity = datastore.prepare(query)
            .asQueryResultList(options);

    assertEquals(6, resultEntity.size());

    // print values
    System.out.println("From ancestor query:");
    System.out.println("All the props: "+resultEntity.get(0).getProperties());
    System.out.println("idx prop: "+resultEntity.get(0).getProperty("chapters_INTEGER_IDX"));
    System.out.println();

    Entity chapter = datastore.get(resultEntity.get(0).getKey());
    System.out.println("All the props: "+chapter.getProperties());
    System.out.println("idx prop: "+chapter.getProperty("chapters_INTEGER_IDX"));

    // test against JUnit
    assertNotNull(resultEntity.get(0).getProperty("chapters_INTEGER_IDX"));
    assertNotNull(chapter.getProperty("chapters_INTEGER_IDX"));
 }
```

Here is the [GitHub-project](https://github.com/micheleorsi/jdo-order-test-project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem!

You should add this line in the jdoconfig.xml:

> `<property name="datanucleus.appengine.storageVersion" value="PARENTS_DO_NOT_REFER_TO_CHILDREN"/>`

Here is the [piece of code](https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/StorageVersion.java) where it is explained the different datastore configurations

Comment: Clearly Google's own testcases *don't* run using the 'ancient storage version' and they handle indexed lists ok. But good you have a "solution".

Comment: Mmhhh... Didn't understand what you meant DataNucleus! The problem was running my own test case in my machine (not in the Google Cloud). So that it seems that JDO doesn't persist anymore INTEGER_IDX by default. Now I am in the process of migrating data in the cloud following this https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/DataMigrationProcess_for_Version2

Comment: The other poster pointed you to tests that run *on your machine*. They demonstrate indexed lists clearly enough. They use, by default, the latest storage version (but also run with older storage versions). They store the ids of the elements in a Collection in a property on the owner. No such artificial INTEGER_IDX property is needed, and relying on such implementation specifics in your code is bad practice. The order is preserved when using this new storage version just like it is with the ancient storage version. Storage of the collection details is more efficient in this new storage version

Comment: mmhhh.. I will review better the samples. My main need to continue using INTEGER_IDX is the possibility to quickly re-order a collection of children without touching the whole collection, but working only on those INTEGER_IDX properties

Answer (score 1):

Why does "Chapter.book" have a mappedBy on it? That is illegal. If a relation is bidirectional then it has a mappedBy at the side that doesn't have the FK.

Comment: thanks so much for your suggestion Neil, but I tried to remove and it still has problems. (I am going to update the sample and the github repo as well)

Comment: Google have plenty of tests under https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fdatanucleus and they include indexed lists; all pass. Look at HasOneToManyListJDO and BidirectionalChildListJDO. Barring that you look in the LOG and debug what is wrong with your config

Comment: Indeed the LOG register all communication with the datastore, about what is stored, and the DB viewer shows what is stored (columns etc), so ought to be simple enough to debug